# Magento : get customer_id from salesOrderList

Tags: magento-1.8, customer, api, soap, sales-order

i try to get orderl list with this API :[salesOrderList (SOAP V2)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/sales/salesOrder/sales_order.list.html)  i use this code :

```
env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        env.dotNet = false;
        env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
        env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
                "salesOrderList");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        //request.addProperty("customerId", id.toString());
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        result = env.getResponse();
        Log.d("order result", result.toString());
```

and result :

```
increment_id=100000001;
                store_id=1; 
                created_at=2013-12-12 07:36:52; 
                updated_at=2013-12-12 07:36:57; 
                tax_amount=0.0000; 
                shipping_amount=0.0000; 
                discount_amount=0.0000; 
                subtotal=246.0000; 
                grand_total=246.0000; 
                total_qty_ordered=2.0000; 
                base_tax_amount=0.0000; 
                base_shipping_amount=0.0000; 
                base_discount_amount=0.0000; 
                base_subtotal=246.0000; 
                base_grand_total=246.0000; 
                billing_address_id=1; 
                billing_firstname=?????; 
                billing_lastname=????; 
                billing_name=????? ????; 
                store_to_base_rate=1.0000; 
                store_to_order_rate=1.0000; 
                base_to_global_rate=1.0000;
                base_to_order_rate=1.0000; 
                weight=0.0000; 
                store_name=Main Website
```

i have big problam ! there is no "customer_id" in result ! how can i get order list with id of order customer ?

Comment: Does this happen for all orders? Maybe the order you check is a guest order and the customer_id is null

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm confirming that `NOT LOGGED IN` orders will assign those customers a `customer_id` of `NULL` Our site briefly allowed people to place orders without being logged in.

This query gets all the sales lines, so has redundant "order level" information:

```
SELECT 
      sfi.updated_at as 'date'
    , sfo.increment_id as 'order'
    , sfo.entity_id as 'sfo.entity_id'
    , sfo.customer_id as 'sfo.customer_id'
    , sfo.customer_firstname as 'sfo.first'
    , sfo.customer_lastname as 'sfo.last'
    , sfo.customer_email as 'sfo.customer_email'
    , sfii.sku as 'sku'
    , sfii.qty as 'qty'
    , sfii.base_row_total as 'row sales'
    , sfi.grand_total as 'order total'
    , LEFT(sfop.additional_information,20) as 'sfop.pmt_details'
    , sfi.shipping_amount as 'shipping'
    , sfii.tax_amount as 'tax_amount'
    , LEFT(sfii.name,20) as 'desc'
FROM 
    sales_flat_invoice_item sfii 
LEFT JOIN 
    sales_flat_invoice sfi ON sfii.parent_id = sfi.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    sales_flat_order sfo ON sfi.order_id = sfo.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN 
    sales_flat_order_payment sfop ON sfop.parent_id = sfo.entity_id 
WHERE 
    sfo.status = 'complete' 
AND
    sfo.customer_id IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    sfo.increment_id DESC
```

In my case there were `596 rows in set (0.47 sec)`.